# Is there any way to declare a scope extension to third party library kotlin class?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying a program build with [Jetbrain/Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) as ORM library and [TornadoFX](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx) which is a kotlin version wrapper of JavaFX as UI Framework.
There is a problem that an entity's class property is delegated by Exposed.

```
object Paintings: UUIDTable() {
    ...
    val description = text("description").default("")
    ...
}

class Painting(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    ...

    var description by Paintings.description

    ...
}
```

And I'm also want to create an property delegated to JavaFX's property like this

```
class Painting(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    ...

    var description by property<String>()
    fun descriptionProperty() = getProperty(Painting::description)

    ...
}
```

There is a conflict here,so I'm trying to build a own delegate class to wrapper two framework's delegated.Maybe build something which can wrap two frameworks's delegate though a infix function extension.

```
class Painting(id: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(id) {
    ...

    var description by Paintings.description notify property<String>()
    fun descriptionProperty() = getProperty(Painting::description)

    ...
}
```

And here is the problem that the operator `setValue` and `getValue` for delegate from Exposed is declare in `Entity` class

```
open class Entity<ID:Comparable<ID>>(val id: EntityID<ID>) {
    ...

    operator fun <T> Column<T>.getValue(o: Entity<ID>, desc: KProperty<*>): T = 
        lookup()

    operator fun <T> Column<T>.setValue(o: Entity<ID>, desc: KProperty<*>, value: T) {...}
```

If I declare a wrapper class it just cannot access the delegate operator for `Column` which is scoped in `Entity` class

```
//Global Extension instead of scoped to `Entity`
infix fun <T> Column<T>.notify(fxProperty: PropertyDelegate<T>) {
    return DelegateWrapper(this,fxProperty)
}

class DelegateWrapper<T>(val column: Column<T>, val fxProperty: PropertyDelegate<T>) {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return column.getValue(...)  <-cannot resolve getValue
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As a work arround I guess I had to build a subclass of UUIDEntity and add those extension as member extension and nest class to make it work.

Comment: Can you please specifically tell me which function in Entity you would like to extend or show some code?

Comment: @notionquest ok I just updated for more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by limiting the type that the delegate can be used with to `Entity`.

This can be done by replacing `thisRef: Any?` with `thisRef: Entity<ID>` and calling the `getValue` extension in a `thisRef.run { ... }` block that provides an `Entitiy<ID>` receiver as follows:

```
class DelegateWrapper<T>(val column: Column<T>, val fxProperty: PropertyDelegate<T>) {

    operator fun <ID : Comparable<ID>> getValue(
        thisRef: Entity<ID>,  // <-- here
        property: KProperty<*>
    ): String =
        thisRef.run { column.getValue(thisRef, property) }  

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) = TODO()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.It is work for me.
But I still hope kotlin will support add member extension from outside as soon as possiable.XD